# Photoshop on Ubuntu or DualBoot with Windows for it?

Tags: 16.04, wine, playonlinux, photoshop

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I must use Photoshop because of my job. I tried to use virtualbox but it's slower and there are some problems about shortkeys. I am thinking to use PlayOnLinux for photoshop but i worry about security.

Should i install windows with dualboot or PlayOnLinux (wine) is secure enough for photoshop ?

Edit: "Security" I mean about viruses. I have D partition old NTFS for backup files and i have external HDD it's NTFS too.

Comment: You might add which security concerns you have in mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "_secure enough_" / "_i worry about security_" ? For things like PS, running it on Windows is more reliable in general, in my experience.

Comment: I mean security about viruses.

Comment: Regarding viruses: You'll be fine with running Photoshop in wine, especially if you don't run any other windows software with it.

Comment: I don't think viruses will be a problem for you if you download software and images from verified sources or create images from scratch. However, if you download images from the Internet, you can get a virus that will not work normally with wine, but you can spread the virus to other computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would likely have less problems with viruses if running Photoshop within wine for a few reasons.

1. A virus might not behave like it would on a real operating system and therefore would do nothing to your wine environment.
2. Your wine environment is easier to backup/restore/recreate compared to reinstalling/restoring Windows OS.
3. Your program running on wine may run faster than running it on Windows, with an antivirus.

Things you should be aware of and you should practice while running Photoshop in wine:

1. Always use a working directory outside of the wine environment so that if you DO happen to get an infected file, you can restore your wine environment without losing your photos.
2. Run an antivirus check on your photos, or USB, before moving it to another machine or OS.  IF you happen to get a virus in wine and your photos get infected, it may not affect YOUR wine environment, but there's still a chance of passing on the virus through the photo files on the next machine.

Comment: If my wine would be in my home directory and my works at D partition (NTFS) it's fine or still my works can be effected from viruses ?

Comment: If you only use wine for Photoshop, and you're **creating** images from scratch, you're fine and will likely never get a virus.  If you download images to work on from the internet or get them from other computers that have a virus, then there's a _chance_ you can get a virus, but again, a virus will likely not work like it's supposed to in wine so the chance of spreading is low.  And 99.9% of viruses can't affect your linux computer, but you can still spread it.  Honestly, you have more chances getting a virus working with PS in Windows even with an antivirus.

Comment: On the other hand, everything you run inside Wine has the same permissions as if it would run natively on Ubuntu under your user account. As far as I know, Wine does not really contain any kind of sandboxing that isolates your file system from the Wine guest applications - they have full access to all available files accessible by you. Whether a malware running under Wine is dangerous for you or not depends only on the malware. And I doubt that it would run faster on Wine than natively on Windows. Bear in mind that Wine has to translate all system calls etc.